# Unknown Error Xcode Flutter while running cmd 'flutter build ipa' in terminal

Tags: xcode, flutter, ipa

While building ipa in Xcode but working fine while building for iphone in Xcode

Comment: Please post error along with question

Comment: there is no error except Encountered error while archiving for device.

Comment: you should have error logs for this command failure :  flutter build ipa

Comment: there are only some warning which are mend to ignored as those warnings come while building in Xcode too but still it is building in xcode

Comment: i also get this error, do you have solution for this? @User5651